# Where is the setting to show the line wrap in Visual Studio / ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I have just setup a new Visual Studio 2015 environment with ReSharper. On my old system in the IDE code editor window, whenever a line was too long, there was a little glyph shown indicating that the line had been wrapped to fit in the editor. (The actual line contents had not been changed).

[image]

I want the little glyph to appear showing me the string has been wrapped.

I cannot remember whether this was a Visual Studio or ReSharper setting or where to set this.

Comment: is that a C# (.cs) file you have posted in your screenshot? if yes have you tried 1) reopening the file 2) restarting VS?

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> -> "Word Wrap"

Default shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>W</kbd>

Comment: this is the shortcut to toggle word wrap and afaik has nothing to do with the glyph OP was asking about, nevertheless, I ended up here because `ctrl + e, w` shortcut was overriden by resharper keyboard layout, the solution was to assign the Edit.ToggleWordWrap shortcut to something else

Answer (score -1):

ReSharper, menu *Options* → *Code Editing* → *C#* → *Formatting Style* → *Line Breaks and Wrapping*.

There is a setting, *Wrap Long Lines*, which you can check/uncheck.

[image]

Also check you don't have Visual Studio word wrap on already (which is separate to ReSharper):

Menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Text Editor* → *C#* → *General*.

[image]

Comment: I have that checked, but the line is not wrapping. Have updated my original post with screenshot of unwrapped string for instance.

Comment: @TheEdge check my update, did you have word wrap on ?